# For a finite field $K$ with $char(K) \neq 2$, showing $[K^*:(K^*)^2]=2$ in two different ways

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

For a finite field $K$ with $char(K) \neq 2$, showing $[K^*:(K^*)^2]=2$ in two different ways.

Let $K$ be a finite field with $char(K) \neq 2$. The mapping $a \rightarrow a^2$ is a homomorphism from $K^*$ to itself with kernel of order $2$ (the kernel will have $1$ and $-1$ only, right???). Hence the image $(K^*)^2$ has order half that of $K^*$, and so $[K^*:(K^*)^2]=2$.

Is this correct? I'm a little iffy about calling the image of the morphism $(K^*)^2$ since I imagine $(K^*)^2=\{ab:a,b \in K\}$ where as i think the image of the morphism as equaling $\{a^2:a \in K\}$.

Also, the fact that $[K^*:(K^*)^2]=2$ is said to follow directly from the fact that $K^*$ is cyclic. I guess if $\left<a\right>=K^*$ then $\left<a^2\right>=\left<a\right>^2=(K^*)^2$ so this makes sense.

Any further insights would be greatly appreciated... Thank you!

Comment: You can call $\{a^2:a\in K^*\}$ however you want, as long as you're coherent with you nomenclature. As for the kernel part, you're right: $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$, so in a field with $char K\neq2$, the polynomial $x^2-1$ has the two (and only) solutions $\pm 1$. If you use the fact that $K^*=\langle a\rangle$ is cyclic, then the quotient $K^*/(K^*)^2$ has only two elements $\{(K^*)^2,a(K^*)^2\}$ (since $m$ in $a^m$ is either even, so $a^m=a^{2k}=(a^2)^k\in(K^*)^2$, or odd, so $a^m=aa^{2k}=a(a^2)^k\in a(K^*)^2$)

Comment: $(K^*)^2=\{a^2:a \in K^*\}$.

Comment: @Alessandro If $Char(K)=2$ then what might other solutions to $x^2-1=0$ look like?

Comment: If $char K=2$, then $-1=1$ and $x^2-1=x^2+1=(x+1)^2$, so there is only one solution